# Run GUI in eclipse android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-relativelayout

I have been working in a android project for the first time, so I created a simple GUI for the app however now that I finish I would like to make some changes to the GUI but it is troublesome, if an object is out of place the app does not run and I can not see where is the problem. Is there anyway in eclipse environment check only GUI without load the Java code? I mean, the Java code is ok, problem is the placement of the objects in `XML` file, it is taking a lot of time to know. I share the structure of `XML` file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:gravity="top"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSongName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Song Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/albumCover"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/music" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/albumCover"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        android:height="64dp"
        android:text="Prev"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        android:width="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/forward"
        android:height="16dp"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        android:width="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/play"
        android:text="Play"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        android:width="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/stop"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        android:width="64dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReplay"
        android:layout_width="49dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/replay_off"
        android:text="Replay"
        android:textSize="0sp" />

    <Button
        android1:id="@+id/btnShuffle"
        android1:layout_width="45dp"
        android1:layout_height="45dp"
        android1:background="@drawable/shuffle_off"
        android1:text="Shuffle"
        android1:textSize="0sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<SeekBar
    android1:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android1:id="@+id/songCurrentDuration"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_above="@+id/seekBar"
    android1:layout_alignLeft="@+id/albumCover"
    android1:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android1:id="@+id/songTotalDuration"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignBottom="@+id/albumCover"
    android1:layout_alignRight="@+id/albumCover"
    android1:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your output GUI can be viewed in Eclipse or Android Studio

Comment: @FrankN.Stein you mean I am missing this </RelativeLayout>? when I edit the question is there, do not know why it is not been displayed

Comment: @AshishAni I know, problem is I can not see the output, it has an error and it is not in the java code, I think is something related to the positions, however I can not see where exactly I am doing wrong. Have you ever encountered this kind of problem? it looks ok before running.

Comment: GUI of layout can be viewed by selecting tab  next to "source" at bottom.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein after TextView is only missing this line
    </RelativeLayout>

Comment: @AshishAni yes, my layout look nice but when I run the emulator it stops, I can not see the interface in the emulator.

Comment: According to me error may be in "?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"

Comment: have u seen the log console for error

Comment: I tried by removing that atributte, something is telling me is the order or the way I use the layouts, it looks well in eclipse GUI, it is like if objects are close to each other everything mess up. No error in the log console

Comment: Why do you have `xmlns:android1`? It is the same as `xmlns:android`

Comment: I guess there's a **conflict** between your LinearLayout's `android:layout_below="@+id/albumCover"` and your next Views `android1:layout_above="@+id/XYZ"`. The ralativity between them just doesn't seem logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is that you have use relative layout as the parent layout, and in all its sub layouts you have never declared relative position between the widgets. That is between two text view or button.

Please update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this did not answer my question, however it helped me. I did not know about the layout and your answer clarified what should I do.

Answer (score 1):

`Right click` on one of the layout files in the `Package Explorer` view and click

```
Open With -> Android Layout Editor
```